# Headers null when making a CORS request with Aurelia-Fetch-Client

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, aurelia, fetch-api

When attempting to retrieve headers from a response using the fetch API(wrapped by the Aurelia-fetch-client) the headers object is empty;

Here's my method to fetch customers

```
 public GetCustomers(): Promise<CustomerList> {

    let  customerList = new CustomerList();
    return this._http.fetch('/api/customers')
    .then(response => {

        let links = response.headers.get('Link');
        customerList.pagination.pageCount = parseInt(response.headers.get('X-Pagination.pageCount'));
        customerList.pagination.pageNumber = parseInt(response.headers.get('X-Pagination.pageNumber'));
        customerList.pagination.pageSize = parseInt(response.headers.get('X-Pagination.pageSize'));
        customerList.pagination.totalItems = parseInt(response.headers.get('X-Pagination.totalItems'));

       console.log(response.headers);
        return  response.json() as any

    }).then(data =>{          
        data.map(
            item => {
                let customer: Customer = new Customer(this);
                Object.assign(customer, item);
                customerList.customers.push(customer);
            });
            return customerList;  
       });
}
```

Http Fetch configuration

```
constructor(private eventAggregator: EventAggregator, url: string) {

    this._http = new HttpClient();

    this._http.configure(config => {
        config
            .withBaseUrl(url)
            .withInterceptor({
                request(request) {
                    console.log(`Requesting ${request.method} ${request.url}`);
                    return request; // you can return a modified Request, or you can short-circuit the request by returning a Response
                },
                response(response) {
                    console.log(`Received ${response.status} ${response.url}`);
                    return response; // you can return a modified Response
                }
            })
            .withDefaults({
                'mode' : 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`

                }
            })
            .useStandardConfiguration();
    });

}
```

Here's what we can see in Chrome. I'm exposing the headers i want.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see any headers from your response at all?

Comment: None. In a chrome debugging session the headers is an empty object.

Comment: I've just tested, and I get the same. If you use the standard `aurelia-http-client` instead then you'll be able to see them I suspect. But, this might lack other features you require.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a bash. Sounds like a potential bug then?

Comment: @MrBliz - find the answer?

Comment: @InquisitorJax i can't remember, if i did, or i found a workaround. I'm in a different company now so can't check.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, when using a CORS policy on the server, you need to specifically opt-in to headers in the response.
ASP.NET Core has a "WithExposedHeaders" method for this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.withexposedheaders?view=aspnetcore-2.0